# Linker error after installing Firebase pod

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, parse-platform, cocoapods

I am a beginner in iOS app development. I am currently working on a project that needs to be changed from Parse to Firebase`.

- I installed cocoa pods and "`firebase/core`" `pod` as `firebase` site instructed.
- Imported firebase.h in appdelegate.h
- Added `[FIRApp configure];` in '`didfinishlaunchingwithoptions`'
- Added '`googleservice-info.plist`' in project.

After doing these steps, I ran the build but it failed with following errors ([Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1aKN.png.))

Showing Recent Issues

```
Ld /Users/../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Example.app/Example
```

Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know this has something to do with the parse code in my project but I don't have much knowledge in Parse or in Firebase.

Please help me with this error and guide me how to successfully migrate from Parse to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used Parse SDK, just make sue you delete `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` library from your project or from your `podfile` remove

```
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
```

Comment: Is it ok to just remove ParseFacebookUtils.framework?  There is also a framework named Parse.framework, do I have to remove that too?

Comment: I think yes. just try :)

Comment: Thanks, the build succeeded. But